# Argument principle or rouche theorem? Complex analysis problem

Tags: complex-analysis

> $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{2 z^{4}-7 z^{3}-2 z-i}{(z-i)^{2}\left(3 z^{2}-z+9\right)^{2}}$
>
> $\displaystyle \oint_{|z|=2} \frac{f^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)} d z=?$

I tried the argument principle and the rouche theorem but could not find it. Thank you very much if you can help! :)

Comment: Big hint: logarithm

Answer (score 0):

The argument principle is what you need.

Recall that it states: for a function $f(z)$ holomorphic inside a circle $C$, except possibly for a finite number of poles, and without poles or zeros on the contour itself, then
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dx = n_1 - n_2$$
where $n_1$ is the number of zeros of $f$ inside $C$ and $n_2$ the number of poles, each counted according to its multiplicity (e.g. See Complex Analysis, Stein and Shakarchi, Princeton Lectures in Analysis, Princeton University Press).

In you example, with a straightforward rational function, just count the number of zeros in the numerator (with multiplicity) less the same calculation for the denominator.